# Do AWS Registered Domains support more than 6 Name Servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain, google-cloud-platform, nameserver

Does AWS support more than 6 name servers for a single domain? The UI (see attached image) appears to reject more than 6 name servers for a domain when trying to add a 7th. Google Cloud seems to allow up to 12. Is this intentional? Are there other methodologies or workarounds?

[image: awsDomainNameServerLimit]
[image: gcpRegistrarSetup]

Comment: The RFCs define no maximum, just a minimum of two. But we can see from your image that something else is wrong: You need to replace the old nameservers, not add to them.

Comment: See https://blog.serverfault.com/2017/01/09/surviving-the-next-dns-attack/ where the conclusion is any number above 4 will provide little value. You should interleave aws and google name servers to reduce the performance penalty when aws or google's name servers are unavailable (assuming you want both and are not making the mistake @michael-hampton suggests).

Comment: @MarkWagner If ALL of Amazon's nameservers are unavailable it's because an EMP went off and we're all living in the Stone Age again. I'm not worried about configuring my domain for this event...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I could see a bad configuration change somewhere in AWS causing all of Amazon's nameservers to be unavailable. I can't speak to their DDOS resistance but my company was affected when dyn's name servers were in 2016.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There are far other possible and more probable causes, as it happened in the past globally for other providers. A single human mistake can sometimes ripples to configuration of all routers or triggers BGP announces that will render all IPs unreachable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need so many and how do you intend to keep them in sync? Do *Google domains* support AXFR from Amazon? If not you're up for inconsistencies between the two sets of nameservers.

Better rethink what you're doing and how. Perhaps share more details what are you trying to achieve as there is rarely a need for so many nameservers.

Comment: We're investigating the ability to use our current domain (hosted in AWS) for a new service that we want to deploy in GCP. We don't want to migrate at this point, but we want to host a sub-domain for this new service on GCP. 

We created a managed zone in GCP but during the Registrar Setup the GCP console suggests that we must use all 4 of its name servers (ns-cloud-d{1…4}googledomains.com) to be covered by the [Cloud DNS SLA.](https://cloud.google.com/dns/sla?hl=en_US&_ga=2.128525775.-2105471364.1553643612). The idea was to add each of these name servers to our existing domain in AWS.

Comment: @BrandenP I see, so it's a completely different issue then. I have added a new answer detailing what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on the OP's comments the problem is that they want to have a new service in GCP with DNS for that service in GCP.

Say your domain is *example.com*. What you need to do is this:

1. In GCP **create a subdomain**, for example `gcp.example.com`.
2. Create any records you need for your new service in the GCP DNS management, e.g. create `coolservice.gcp.example.com`.
3. In AWS Route53 **create a NS record** in `example.com` for name `gcp.example.com` with the list of 4 nameservers provided by Google.
4. If you need to refer to the GCP service from your main domain, e.g. as `coolservice.example.com` you can **create a CNAME** in AWS Route53 pointing to the GCP name `coolservice.gcp.example.com`.

Alternatively *don't worry about DNS in GCP at all* and simply create the required records for the GCP services in AWS Route53. Not always possible if you want to rely on tight integration between your service and GCP DNS but if you can use statically allocated IPs for *A records* or can use *CNAME records* this is probably the easiest thing to do for start.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Awesome. I marked your original answer as the accepted one because it more directly pertains to the original question. I'll update here once I get a chance to validate you're prescribed steps above. Thanks a ton!

Comment: We tested the above solution and it works well! We were curious if it is possible to make HTTPS calls to this Route 53 CNAME (i.e. coolservice.example.com) if it points to a GCP load balancer with an associated SSL certificate. We attempted to make API calls through the Route 53 endpoint but we had issues related to verifying our SSL certificate: "SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name". We figure this is because we're used to having Route 53 point to an ELB with an SSL Certificate in the same domain, but this subdomain strategy changes this architecture.

Comment: @BrandenP When you create the SSL certificate you can specify any number of hostnames it will be valid for. Typically you create a single cert for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. Simply add include the names you want to use, e.g. `coolservice.example.com` and `coolservice.gcp.example.com` and `www.coolservice.example.com` etc. These additional names are the “alternative subject names” that your browser complained about. Bottom line: recreate the SSL cert with all the names you want to use.